# The argument "ami" is required, but no definition was found

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I am new to terraform, I am learning modules. I am stuck in a problem.

I have modules folder as root which contain two folders `EC2` and `IAM` and they have terraform code in them. In the same modules folder I have `main.tf` file which is a module file for calling EC2 instance terraform code.

For your information, EC2 instance folder contain two files one for instance resource and second is for defining variables.

My EC2 file looks like this.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the AWS Provider

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count         = "${var.ec2_count}"
  ami           = "${var.ami}"
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"

  tags = {
    Name = "App_Instance"
  }
}
```

My `Variable.tf` file looks like this.

```
variable "ec2_count" {
    type = number
    default = 1
}

variable "ami" {
  type = string
}

variable "instance_type" {
  type = string
}
```

My `main.tf` file looks like this.

```
module "EC2" {
    source = "./EC2"
}
```

Now I want that when I type `terraform plan` command, it should take input at the command prompt but it is showing me below error.

PS: I don't want to pass the value of the variable in the module.

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\AWS_Modules\Modules>terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 1, in module "EC2":
│    1: module "EC2" {
│
│ The argument "ami" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 1, in module "EC2":
│    1: module "EC2" {
│
│ The argument "instance_type" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Comment: `PS: I don't want to pass the value of the variable in the module.` - you have to pass a variable to the module, otherwise this wont work. Terraform will ask you for inputs for variables used in your `main.tf`, but wont ask for inputs required by a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to modules, there are a few things to consider:

1. Where are you defining the variables
2. How are you passing the values to variables **required** by the module

Ideally, you would pass the values to variables when calling the module:

```
module "EC2" {
    source = "./EC2"
    
    ami           = "ami-gafadfafa"
    instance_type = "t3.micro"
}
```

However, since you said you do not want to do that, then you need to assign the default values to variables on the **module level**. This can be achieved with:

```
variable "ec2_count" {
  type = number
  default = 1
}

variable "ami" {
  type    = string
  default = "ami-gafadfafa"
}

variable "instance_type" {
  type    = string
  default = "t3.micro" 
}
```

This way, if you do not provide values when calling the module, the instance will be created and you are still leaving the option to provide the values if someone else were to use your module.

The third option is to have a separate `variables.tf` file in the root module (i.e., the same directory where you are calling the module from) and not define the values for variables. It would be basically a copy+paste of the file you have on the module level without defining any default values. Here is an example:

```
# variables.tf on the root module level
variable "ec2_count" {
  type = number
}

variable "ami" {
  type = string
}

variable "instance_type" {
  type = string
}
```

However, in this case, it is impossible **not to use the input variable names when calling the module**. For this to work with providing the values on the CLI, the code would have to change to:

```
module "EC2" {
    source = "./EC2"
    
    ec2_count     = var.ec2_count
    ami           = var.ami
    instance_type = var.instance_type
}
```

There is no other way the module can know how to map the values you want it to consume without actually setting those variables to a certain value when calling the module.

Comment: I got your point. But when I am using default values and running the command. It doesn't automatically ask me for the variable input instead it is creating the instance with the provided default values.

Comment: Yes, so you want to enter them manually from the command line?

Comment: Yes that's what I had mentioned earlier.

Comment: Missed that part, will update my answer accordingly.